Ubuntu 22.04.4 and 24.04 both crash amd igpu problem or something else?
As I was bored of the popular os that all of us know, I decided to give linux a try. Ubuntu was recommended because of its easy interface and usability everywhere.
I bought a system consisting of :
Amd Ryzen 7900
AsRock B650 Pro RS
Samsung Nvme 980 Pro
32 Gb Crucial Ram 4800 DDR5
As I do not need any external gpu for my work, I decided to use igpu inside 7900 cpu.
Using Rufus, I made an installation USB for both Ubuntu 22.04.4 and 24.04. Both of them crashed when the desktop launched so I started the installation and completed it in safe graphics mode with 24.04.
When I started the computer from HDD, in the login screen, freezes and black screens started appearing. Also I noticed some millimetric artifacts on the screen. I couldn't even shut down the system because of freezes. They remind me of out of sync gpu errors when windows vista was first released.
Tried updating and upgrading ubuntu installation from recovery mode and although it completed successfully crashes still continued.
I tried amdgpu.dpm=0 and amdgpu.aspm=0, dpm froze the boot process while aspm didn't work. Only nomodeset worked for me.
How would you advice I proceed? I have experience with computers but not much in linux or ubuntu, so your advice would be welcome...
UPDATE : After spending 3 days, I decided to add an external GPU and the problem persisted. Windows 11 install also froze with video artifacts, and in service, technicians wasn't able to install amd adrenaline drivers. Seems like either 7900 , B650ProRS or 4800 crucial ram was incompatible with each other or one of them was doa. I had no way of finding out which part was responsible for the crashes and shop assistants was also of no help as they don't have backup parts to test. They recommended I use windows 11 without installing any drivers (I'm not joking)! I forced them to send all parts for RMA.

After spending 3 days, I decided to add an external GPU and the problem persisted. Windows 11 install also froze with video artifacts, and in service, technicians wasn't able to install amd adrenaline drivers. Seems like either 7900 , B650ProRS and 4800 crucial ram was incompatible with each other or one of them was doa. I had no way to find out which part was responsible for the crashes and shop assistants was also of no help as they don't have backup parts to test. They recommended I use windows 11 without installing any drivers (I'm not joking)! I forced them to send all parts for RMA.
